# Need Xpath or anything to identify the elements unique for using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

1)for e-file :

```html
<mat-list-item class="mat-list-item ng-star-inserted" style="">
   <div class="mat-list-item-content">
       <div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
       <div class="mat-list-text"></div>
       <a class="loggedInListItem mat-list-item" mat-list-item="" tabindex="0">
           <div class="mat-list-item-content">
               <div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
               <div class="mat-list-text"></div>e-File <!---->
               <mat-icon class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-icon-no-color ng-star-inserted" role="img" aria-hidden="true">expand_less</mat-icon>
           </div>
       </a>
   </div>
</mat-list-item>
```

2)for income tax returns

```html
<mat-list-item class="mat-list-item ng-star-inserted" style=""><div class="mat-list-item-content"><div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div><div class="mat-list-text"></div><a class="loggedInListItem mat-list-item" mat-list-item="" tabindex="0"><div class="mat-list-item-content"><div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div><div class="mat-list-text"></div>Income Tax Returns <!----><mat-icon class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-icon-no-color ng-star-inserted" role="img" aria-hidden="true">expand_less</mat-icon></div></a></div></mat-list-item>
```

3. for form 26

```html
<mat-list-item class="mat-list-item ng-star-inserted" style=""><div class="mat-list-item-content"><div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div><div class="mat-list-text"></div><a class="loggedInListItem mat-list-item" mat-list-item="" tabindex="0"><div class="mat-list-item-content"><div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div><div class="mat-list-text"></div>View Form 26AS <!----></div></a></div></mat-list-item>
```

i want to select form 26 in sub menu, when I keep my mouse cursor on "e-file" it shows options in those my cursor should move on "income tax returns and it shows options in those options I should click and select "form 26" please help me with a solution

Comment: Can share URL or HTML source?

Comment: just update your question with these html source don't put it in the comment section

Comment: e file HTML--<mat-list-item class="mat-list-item ng-star-inserted" style=""><div class="mat-list-item-content"><div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div><div class="mat-list-text"></div><a class="loggedInListItem mat-list-item" mat-list-item="" tabindex="0"><div class="mat-list-item-content"><div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div><div class="mat-list-text"></div>e-File <!---><mat-icon class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-icon-no-color ng-star-inserted" role="img" aria-hidden="true">expand_less</mat-icon></div></a></div></mat-list-item>

Comment: income tax html--<mat-list-item class="mat-list-item ng-star-inserted" style=""><div class="mat-list-item-content"><div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div><div class="mat-list-text"></div><a class="loggedInListItem mat-list-item" mat-list-item="" tabindex="0"><div class="mat-list-item-content"><div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div><div class="mat-list-text"></div>Income Tax Returns <!----><mat-icon class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-icon-no-color ng-star-inserted" role="img" aria-hidden="true">expand_less</mat-icon></div></a></div

Comment: form 26 html---<mat-list-item class="mat-list-item ng-star-inserted" style=""><div class="mat-list-item-content"><div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div><div class="mat-list-text"></div><a class="loggedInListItem mat-list-item" mat-list-item="" tabindex="0"><div class="mat-list-item-content"><div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div><div class="mat-list-text"></div>View Form 26AS <!----></div></a></div></mat-list-item>

Comment: [edit] your question to include the HTML. Adding these as comments is not helpful.

Comment: I Updated but they are not getting displayed @YaDav MaNish

Comment: now please look those 3 are the HTML script for e file , tax Return and form 26 
when my curson go on e file and go to tax return and then go to form 26 and click it

Comment: "Updated but they are not getting displayed" - because you did not tag these as code. I've edited your question for you.

Comment: I believe it's an indian ITR return website, but still can you confirm with URL ? I have my own creds, I can check it for you.

Comment: Thank you please help me with solution how can I keep my curson on "e-file" and after on income tax and after on form 26 and click it @Justin Ezequiel

Comment: https://www.incometax.gov.in/iec/foportal Url for the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's all a mouse hover, first on `e-file` and then `income tax returns` and then finally click on `form 26`. So basically we need ActionsChain to mouse hover :-

**Sample code  :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//mat-icon[contains(text(), 'expand_more')])[3]/..")))).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Income Tax Returns ']/..")))).perform()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='View Form 26AS']/.."))).click()
```

**Imports  :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**Update 1 :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
e_file = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),' Dashboard')]/../following-sibling::a")))
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(e_file).perform()
action.move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Income Tax Returns ']/..")))).perform()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='View Form 26AS']/.."))).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below code,

```
user_id = driver.find_element_by_id("panAdhaarUserId")user_id.send_keys("UserName")

continue_button= driver.find_element_by_class_name("large-buttonprimary")continue_button.click()

wait3=WebDriverWait(driver,10)element5=wait3.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='mat-checkbox-inner-container']")))

element5.click()


wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'loginPasswordField'))
element.send_keys("Password")

wait2 = WebDriverWait(driver,10)element4= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"large-button-primary")))
element4.click()

action = ActionChains(driver)
element1=driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//a[@id='navBar'])[1])")
element2=driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//div[@id='cdk-overlay-4']//child::div//child::div//child::button)[1])")

element3=driver.find_element_by_xpath
("//span[contains(text(),'File Income Tax Return')]")

action.move_to_element(element1)
.move_to_element(element2).move_to_element(element3).perform()
```

**Imports**

```
from selenium import  webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```